# Use different network interface for RabbitMQ virtual hosts

Tags: rabbitmq, centos7

I have 4 network interface on the server and I want to use 40,000 socket per virtual host and bind each virtual host to specific network interface in RabbitMQ on CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ does not support binding virtual hosts with network interfaces.

You can specify multiple network interfaces RabbitMQ server would be listening on (see [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#interfaces)), but as long as client connects and authenticates properly, it can access any virtual hosts it is authorized to.

The only possible solution would be to deploy 4 separate RabbitMQ server instances, each with different virtual host & listening on a different interface. With [shovel plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) doing the mirroring between brokers (if you need messages to be transferred between virtual hosts).